# Using isUpper, isLower, and isDigit in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am having trouble with how to use isUpper, isLower, and isDigit.  Specifically I am trying to take a string and return a list of tuples for each character in the string containing three Bool values for if the character is an uppercase letter, a lowercase letter, or a digit.  So the string "Ab2" would return the list [(True, False, False), (False, True, False), (False, False, True)]. This is what I have:

```
import Data.Char
uppercaseList :: [a] -> [(Bool, Bool, Bool)]
uppercaseList xs = [(isUpper, isLower, isDigit)]
```

I think I need to pass the character of the string into isUpper, isLower, and isDigit, but I don't see how to. I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, but nothing I've found addresses my confusion so far.

Comment: Do you know about list comprehension? Or the function `map` and lambdas `\x -> (isUpper x, isLower x, isDigit x)`?

Comment: Btw you should change the first part of your type signature to `[Char]` or `String`. `[a]` represents a list of arbitrary elements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to do check on each element of the list (`xs`). Usually this kind of task is done by using `map`

```
import Data.Char
uppercaseList :: String -> [(Bool, Bool, Bool)]
uppercaseList xs = map (\x -> (isUpper x, isLower x, isDigit x)) xs
```

or list comprehension

```
uppercaseList xs = [ (isUpper x, isLower x, isDigit x) | x <- xs ]
```

or write from scratch

```
uppercaseList [] = []
uppercaseList (x:xs) = (isUpper x, isLower x, isDigit x) : uppercaseList xs
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your approach:

```
uppercaseList xs = [(isUpper, isLower, isDigit)]
```

is that it **does not take the list `xs` into account at all**: it is not mentioned in the body. So that means `xs` has no impact on the output.

What you have done ihere is constructing a list as output with *one* element: a tuple that contains *three functions* (yes these are functions, not `Bool`s).

In order to inspect the character, you need to *call* the functions on an element of the list.

Calling a function on a list is done with `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`. Map takes as first argument a function `f`, and as second argument a list of elements (for instance `[x1, x2, x3, x4]`). It applies the function `f` on all elements of the input, and generates a list `[f x1, f x2, f x3, f x4]`). This is done in a lazy manner.

Here we thus need a function `f :: Char -> (Bool, Bool, Bool)`. Based on the specifications, the function looks like:

```
import Data.Char(isUpper, isLower, isDigit)

f :: Char -> (Bool, Bool, Bool)
f x = (isUpper x, isLower x, isDigit x)
```

We can then write:

```
uppercaseList :: [Char] -> [(Bool, Bool, Bool)]
uppercaseList = map f
```

Since it is weird to see a function `f` (we can of course give it a more semantical name), at the top level of a file. We can decide to scope it (or use a *lambda expression* instead):

```
uppercaseList :: [Char] -> [(Bool, Bool, Bool)]
uppercaseList = map f
    where f x = (isUpper x, isLower x, isDigit x)
```